# Is there any way to keep conditional formatting after clearing content in excel sheet when using xlwings?

Tags: python, excel, conditional-formatting, xlwings

I have written a piece of code that clears all data from a sheet in an excel macro-enabled workbook and loads a data frame. After a lot of digging, I found out that the best library is Xlwings. However, after using clear() method, the existing formatting in the xlsm disappears. Is there any way to preserve the formatting?

Comment: Use [clear_contents()](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/latest/api/range.html#xlwings.Range.clear) instead. `clear_contents()` reflects the same operation as in Excel. See the link for the actions of `clear()`, `clear_contents()` and `clear_formats()`.

Comment: Thank you. If you could upload it as answer, to upvote it, it would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Xlwings [clear_contents()](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/latest/api/range.html#xlwings.Range.clear) instead.

The function `clear_contents()` reflects the same operation as in Excel.

See the link for more details about the actions of the three Xlwings clear functions;

- `clear()`
  Clears the content and the formatting of a Range.
- `clear_contents()`
  Clears the content of a Range but leaves the formatting.
- `clear_formats()`
  Clears the format of a Range but leaves the content.